# Installing freezes/doesn't boot on Asus N552VX

Tags: boot, xubuntu, asus, freeze

Hi I just got the new Asus N552VX and am trying to get Xubuntu working on it. I have tried both the 14.04 LTS and the 15.14. However in the install I get ACPI PCC probe failed, sometimes it just crashes right there and sometimes it keeps on going but seemingly random freezes up and wont do anything until I restart. I  googled that one and to my knowledge there seems to not one ACPI-driver that fits this particular laptop. I have gotten as far as installing and booting into the OS but the mousepad and keyboard won't work and after a restart it won't boot into xubuntu again. So has anyone else got ubuntu working on the asus N552VX?

Footnote: When it freezes I can't seem to get an error message, I know you can tap the right arrowbutton to see verbose output (of some sort)  but I can't indentify the problem.

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 0):

The linux kernel is having problems with the HQ6700 CPU: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109081

Thread comments say wait for kernel 4.6, but some "get it to work" with 4.4 and some special boot arguments.